# asp.net mvc 3 - call nonaction from other controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 controllers `CustomerController` and `PrivatemessageController`

Customers has a nonaction method

```
private readonly ICustomerService _customerService; 
public Customer(....)   << autofac Ioc 
{
 }

    [NonAction]
    protected CustomerNavigationModel GetCustomerNavigationModel(Customer customer)
    {
        var model = new CustomerNavigationModel();

        .... _customerSerice...
        return model;
    }
```

I'd like to get `GetCustomerNavigationModel` value from `CustomerController` as I don't want to recreate the same method for `PrivateMessageController`, is that possible in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind here.

1. Make the method public static:

   ```
       [NonAction]
       public static CustomerNavigationModel GetCustomerNavigationModel(Customer customer)
       {
           var model = new CustomerNavigationModel();

           .... _customerSerice...
           return model;
       }
   ```
2. Create a base controller and implement the method there. Have both your controllers derive from your base controller:

   ```
   public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
   {
       [NonAction]
       protected CustomerNavigationModel GetCustomerNavigationModel(Customer customer)
       {
           var model = new CustomerNavigationModel();

           .... _customerSerice...
           return model;
       }
   }


   public class CustomerController : MyBaseController
   {
       ....
   }

   public class PrivatemessageController : MyBaseController
   {
       ....
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the method into a separate class and use that class from your controllers. You can also just make the method static, and call it from *PrivatemessageController* using:

```
CustomerController.GetCustomerNavigationModel(customer);
```